# How to display multi column in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have used bootstrap dropdown control **(below Tag)** in react js application.It works fine as per my requirement.I would like to know how to show multi column in dropdown.For example I need to display **Customer Code and Customer Name** in dropdown

```
<select class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know react, but you must define the row and cols inside your dropdown code and fire the stopPropagation() event on click or hover to prevent the dropdown closes itself after doing a click in the container.